# Proving $Im(A^*)=N(A)^\perp$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A:E \rightarrow F$ be a linear mapping and E,F two finite-dimension inner vector spaces. I want to prove that 
1) $N(A^*)=Im(A)^\bot$
2) $Im(A^*)=N(A)^\bot$
3) $N(A)=Im(A^*)^\bot$
4) $Im(A)=N(A^*)^\bot$

Where $A^*$ is the adjoint of $A$ and $\bot$ denotes the orthogonal complement, i.e., $Im(A)^\bot$, for example, is the set whose elements are orthogonal to all vectors of $Im(A)$. I managed to prove (1) this way:

1) $v\in N(A^*) \Rightarrow A^*v=0 \Rightarrow <u,A^*v>=0, \forall u\in E \Rightarrow <Au,v>=0, \forall u\in E \Rightarrow v \in Im(A)^\bot$.

I want some help to prove (2),(3),(4). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your prove of (1) note that you have to replace the $\Rightarrow$ by $\iff $, because as written, you only proved $\def\N{\mathop{\rm N}}\N(A^*) \subseteq \def\Im{\mathop{\rm Im}}\Im(A)^\bot$.

For (2) just apply (1) to $A^*$, using $A^{**} = A$, giving $\N(A) = \Im(A^*)^\bot$, now take orthogonal complements and use that your spaces are finite-dimensional.

(3) and (4) are (1) and (2) applied to $A^*$.

---

Addendum. If you want to prove (2) as you did with (1), say, you can do this as follows: Let $v \in \Im(A^*)$, say $v = A^*w$, for any $x \in \N(A)$ we have $\def\sp#1{\left<#1\right>}$
$$ \sp{v, x} = \sp{A^*w, x} = \sp{w, Ax} = \sp{w, 0} = 0 $$
so $v \in \N(A)^\bot$. So we have $\Im(A^*) \subseteq \N(A)^\bot$. Counting dimensions, we have 
\begin{align*}
  \dim\N(A)^\bot &= \dim E - \dim \N(A)\\ 
&= \dim E - \bigl(\dim E - \dim \Im(A)\bigr) \\ 
&= \dim\Im(A)\\
&= \dim\Im(A^*)
\end{align*}
So we must have $\Im(A^*) = \N(A)^\bot$.

Comment: Good morning, Martini. Ok, but I search a direct proof of (2), (3) and (4).

Comment: In what way is the given proof "indirect"?

Comment: Added something for (2). (3) and (4) are **exactly** the same as (1) and (2), just exchange $A$ and $A^*$. You can do this for yourself, I'm sure.

Comment: Thank you, Martini. Your explanation in "adendum" was very clear!

Comment: I think this is another way to prove the second part of (2): $v \in N(A)^\bot \rightarrow <v,x>=0, \forall x \in N(A)$.But $x \in N(A) \rightarrow Ax=0. Then, \forall w \in F, <Ax,w>=<x,A^*w>=0$. This implies $<v,x>=<x,A^*w> \Rightarrow v=A^*w \Rightarrow v \in Im(A^*)$

Comment: But $\def\sp#1{\left<#1\right>}$$\sp{v,x} = \sp{A^*w, x}$ for all $x \in {\rm N}(A)$ *does not* imply $v = A^*w$, but only $v- A^*w \in {\rm N}(A)^\bot$.