# Showing that $\left(\operatorname{Im}\left(T^*\right)\right)^\perp=(\ker T)$ (solution verification)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, solution-verification

I have been told that my proof is not true at all without any explanation why, I would like if any one can help.

Let $T: V\to V$ linear operator in finite inner product space, show that $$\left(\operatorname{Im}\left(T^*\right)\right)^\perp=(\ker T)$$

**My attempt:**

$\left(\operatorname{Im}\left(T^*\right)\right)^\perp=(\ker T) \iff \operatorname{Im}(T^*)^=\ker\left(T^{}\right)^\perp$

Let  $\vec v\in Im(T^*) $ and let $\vec w \in \ker(T)$ so we can write :

$\langle T^*(v),w\rangle=\langle v,T(w)\rangle=\langle v,0\rangle=0$

Comment: [Proving $Im(A^*)=N(A)^\bot$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/528461/721644) and 
[Prove that $R(T^{*})^\perp =N(T)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1676604/721644)

Comment: @Invisible it seems that he showed exactly like I did, or maybe I missed something, It is really important for me to understand why my assumption is wrong (or maybe the teacher made a mistake by checking my proof)